# Refreshing sort cache in Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I can see that Jquery datatables generates a sorting cache when the table is first initialized using the [table.columns().cache()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().cache()) method.  One of my columns contains td elements that have a span with classes on it.  Example:

```
<tr>...<td><span class="SpanColors red"></span></td>...</tr>
...
<tr>...<td><span class="SpanColors blue"></span></td>...</tr>
```

My sorting of this particular column depends on the class that is on the span.  I have written a text-based column sorting function to do this, as described [here](https://datatables.net/development/sorting).

In my table, I am dynamically updating rows in this way:

```
var id = //some guid
var newClassToAdd = 'yellow';
var rows = table.rows().nodes();
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = $(rows[i]);
    var span = row.find('td span.SpanColors')
    if (span && span.data('id') == id) {
        span.removeClass('red blue yellow');
        span.addClass(newClassToAdd);
    }
}
```

The issue that I am running into is that when I do this, the cache isn't updated so when sorting, the rows appear in the same order as prior to when I updated them.

Is there some method that can be used to update this cache after rows are updated?  I have searched the internet, but apparently this isn't a problem that many people are having.  Perhaps if I were updating my rows in a different (more legitimate) way, the cache, might refresh on its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use [`row().invalidate()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().invalidate()) after you're done modifying cell content.

```
table.row(rows[i]).invalidate('dom');
```

After all rows are invalidated you may need to call [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) to redraw the table.