# Javascript - Refresh column order of Datatables after edit to rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a javascript that updates the cells of a Datatable row after a successfully returned ajax call which updates the database. All's good. Now I want to refresh the sorting of the Datatable since the data has changed but I cannot figure out how to do this.

I don't know if you need to see my code. I'm thinking I just need the datatable function to reorder a column, but I can find it in the manuals. So here's my code for you gurus.

Here's my HTML

```
<button id="edit_row" class="btn btn-warning" style="display:none;">EDIT</button>
<table id="tabledata" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>day of year</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>poem</th>
        <th>poet</th>                    
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $row->dayofyear?></td>
        <td><?= $row->nicedate?></td>
        <td><?= $row->ndp_id?></td>
        <td><?= $row->pm_name?></td>
        <td><?= $row->poet?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // ---------------------------------------
  // load datatabes
  // ---------------------------------------
    $('#tabledata').DataTable({
     columnDefs: [
         { targets: 2, visible: false }    
     ]
  });

  // ---------------------------------------
  // global variables use for updating row data
  // ---------------------------------------
  table = $('#tabledata').DataTable();
  row = '';
  row_data = [];

  // ---------------------------------------
  // highlight selected table row & show 'edit' button upon row click 
  // ---------------------------------------
  $('#tabledata tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

    if ( $(this).hasClass('trselected') ) {
      $(this).removeClass('trselected');
      $("#edit_row").hide("slow");
    } else {
      $("#tabledata tbody tr").removeClass("trselected");
      $(this).addClass('trselected');
      $("#edit_row").show("slow");
    }

    //save row data for use later
    row = table.row( this );    
    row_data = table.row( this ).data();
  });

  // ---------------------------------
  //  The edit button has been clicked
  // ---------------------------------
  $( "#edit_row" ).click(function() {

    location_id=parseInt(row_data[2]); //get database id from hidden cell

    //Ajax Form into Popup
    $.ajax({
       url: 'edit_ndp_schedule.form.php?wnu_ndpID='+location_id,
       error: function() { alert('failed to load form'); },
       success: function(data) {

          $('#popup_content').html(data); // loads edit form into popup
          $('#popup').bPopup(); // shows powpup

          //Events for when the popup form has been submitted
          $('#edit_member_form').submit(function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault(); //prevents form form submitting

            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                  try {
                      json = $.parseJSON(data);

                      //update selected datatable row to show edits to station
                      row_data[0] = json['date1'];
                      row_data[1] = json['date2'];
                      row.data(row_data);
                      table.order();
                      //REFRESH ORDER OF COLUMNS HERE

                  } catch (e) { //if returned data isnt json, then its probably and error message
                      alert(data); 
                  }

                  $("#popup").bPopup().close(); //close popup

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert('fail');
                }

            });//close ajax form send
          })//close ajax form open success
       }
    });//close ajax form open
  }); //end click edit button
}); // end document ready
```

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187508/refreshing-sort-cache-in-jquery-datatable

Comment: T.Shah, That did it!. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

T.Shah pointed me to the answer

In short, one line in the above code was changed.
Form this:

```
table.order();
```

To this:

```
row.invalidate().draw();
```

Since Datatables orders from cache and not from what's in the table, refreshing the order from an edited table doesn't work. The row that is changed must be marked as invalid `invalidate()` (so Datatable will know that row needs to be updated in cache), then the table needs to be redrawn `draw()`. 
Works like a charm